# Upgraded iphone now won't sync calendars or contacts!

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, upgrade

I recently upgraded my iphone 4 to the new operating system and now I have lots of problems.

- it is not syncing calendars or contacts with my Vista system in outlook
- i can't add appointments or new contacts directly into the iphone

I'm going crazy. If anyone can help me I would be very grateful!
Thanks
T

Comment: Can you explain the problems in more detail? What happens when you try to sync? What happens when you try to add appointments or contacts?

Comment: If I go into the info page and tick sync contact with outlook when I hit apply it starts the sync process and then the ticks disappear and it doesn't sync them.

Comment: When I go into the contacts or the calendar function on the iphone the + sign is missing so I can't add any new entries. I can edit existing entries - this bit is fine.

Comment: This is guesswork, hence comment not answer.  But take a backup up your phone, then remove your accounts in the settings apps.  Re-add them, pointing them at your sync service in the same way, and possible add/remove the setting within outlook.

Comment: I reviewed your responses, but I don't know how to proceed as I'm not familiar with the issues you're having. Hopefully someone else will!

Answer (score 1):

Turn on iCloud in the Settings. There are options for Mail, Contacts, Calendars, etc. You need to turn on the appropriate service.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't activate iCloud at the time of the software pdate because I don't know anything about it and thought I could figure that out later. I have now totally restored the phone (on the advice of apple, which has restored the + sign in calendars and contacts) however even though I've done this and activated iCloud my sync problem is still there - I can't sync to my outlook. Any other thoughts? I'm going crazy here. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just spent an hour on the phone with the apple guys and it seems that it was a problem with iTunes. We unistalled iTunes and a series of other apple software applications and updates (in a specific order) rebooted then reinstalled iTunes and the problem was resolved. We are all good to go! Working again! Brilliant!!! Apparently the whole iCloud thing may have been the reason the applecart was upset. Passing on the fix to you guys in case you come across it again. Cheers!